# Scanner class Java not working with german letters

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a program that reads a text file for german words and outputs them(currently using latest JDK and BlueJ as IDE) but I have a problem when the program encounters any german letter it doesn't work. Please note that I'm using a generalised methods setup as this isn't my final intention with the program. (when I use a text file with only english letters it works perfectly but when there is a german letter the output terminal doesnt even pop up).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    static Scanner file;
    static Scanner file2;
    static Scanner x;
    public static void openFile(){
        try{
            file = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void doFile(){
        while(file.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(file.next());
       }
    }
    public static void closeFile(){
        file.close();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        openFile();
        doFile();
        closeFile();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the encoding you are using by default

Answer (score 3):

Might be an encoding mismatch problem, as Alfabravo has pointed out. What exactly goes wrong?

Try

```
file = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"), "UTF-8");
```

or

```
file = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"), "ISO-8859-1");
```